# Angular2 Material select dropdown does not close after it is opened

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am new to Node and I am trying to use the [dropdown from Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview).  The problem is that once the dropdown is opened it cannot be closed (by clicking another region of the page), a secondary problem is that the dropdown list is not fitting in the bootstrap grid that it is placed in.  Below is an image of the opened dropdown

[image]

Here is the Material dependency lines in my `package.json` folder (obviously there are other dependencies as well).

```
"@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
```

I am using submodules in my project so in the parent module I am including the imports (there are other imports as well but these are the relevant ones)

```
imports: [
    MatSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
]
```

and in the child module I include the identical imports.

In the actual component which uses the dropdown I have the html

```
<div class="row col-sm-5">
         <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
                 </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

and the relevant typescript is

```
toppings = new FormControl();

toppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: did you import material theme?, also i think best is to put `row` and `col` into 2 separate elements

Comment: @Hussein No I thought that was optional, I'll give it a try though

Comment: @Hussein I added `<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">` to my index.hbs file but it did not seem to change anything

Comment: make sure the styles in it are applied by checking in dev tools

Comment: @Hussein I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: just right click on any angular material component in the page and select `inspect` then check the styles tab, if you see some styles applied then the css is imported correctly

Comment: @Hussein ok there's something there.  One of them is `.mat-option-text { ...`  so I assume that means its being applied

Comment: @Hussein but when I remove the `<link ...` the same style content is there so maybe it isn't being applied, I don't know

Comment: idk man you are doing something wrong, just try to follow the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: check this too: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: yes those are the resources I have been using from the beginning

Comment: @Hussein You were right.  My path to the css file was wrong.  I corrected it and now it works.  Thanks for your help and feel free to add this as an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include one of the material themes into your main css/sass file:

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

or add it in your index.html `head` tag